# Android app stops logging to console when screen is off

Tags: android, xamarin, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm creating an app that detects Mobile Data status change and logs something to the console. This app uses a wakeful broadcast receiver to do so.

It works **fine** when screen is **on**, but **not** when screen is **turned off** (It doesn't log anything to the console).

I'm using **C#/Xamarin** on an **Android 4.0.3** device but it's code should be very **familiar** to java users. This app also has the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Here is the entire app:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.Content;
using Android.Telephony;

namespace DataChangeDetector
{
    [Activity(Label = "DataChangeDetector", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        //private TelephonyManager tManager;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            SendBroadcast(new Intent(this, typeof(DataChangeHandler)));
        }
    }

    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
    public class DataChangeHandler : WakefulBroadcastReceiver
    {
        public static void SetUp(Context context)
        {
            TelephonyManager tManager = TelephonyManager.FromContext(context);
            tManager.Listen(new CustomPhoneStateListener(context), PhoneStateListenerFlags.DataActivity);
        }

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnReceive");
            SetUp(context);
        }
    }

    public class CustomPhoneStateListener : PhoneStateListener
    {
        private Context mContext;
        private static readonly TimeSpan MinInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8); // 8 Seconds
        private readonly Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch(); // Stopped initially

        public CustomPhoneStateListener(Context context)
        {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public override void OnDataActivity(DataActivity direction)
        {
            base.OnDataActivity(direction);
            if (direction == DataActivity.In)
            {
                stopwatch.Restart();
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved Data");
            }
            else if (direction == DataActivity.None)
            {
                if (stopwatch.IsRunning && stopwatch.Elapsed < MinInterval)
                {
                    return;
                }
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No Data");
                    // TODO: Reset the data
                }
                finally
                {
                    stopwatch.Restart();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
It doesn't log anything to the console when screen is off, not even system logs. (My Nexus 5 logs the system logs and app logs even with screen turned off)

When running the app from IDE with screen turned off it only loads some .net assemblies and that's it. Last lines from console:

```
Loaded assembly: System.dll
04-03 13:38:10.510 D/libEGL  (16322): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX530_125.so
04-03 13:38:10.522 D/libEGL  (16322): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX530_125.so
04-03 13:38:10.528 D/libEGL  (16322): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX530_125.so
04-03 13:38:10.610 D/OpenGLRenderer(16322): Enabling debug mode 0
04-03 13:38:10.631 V/KeyEvent(16322): Reset: android.view.KeyEvent$DispatcherState@4186b6f8
04-03 13:38:10.682 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16322): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

This app only needs to run on this particular device (LG P970) and OS (4.0.3 ICS).

Comment: Which part of the code in question do you call a "wakeful broadcast receiver"? I see a bunch of code, that registers simple listener. Listeners aren't supposed to wake up device.

Comment: @user1643723 `public class DataChangeHandler : WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, and I call it in MainActivity `SendBroadcast(new Intent(this, typeof(DataChangeHandler)));`

Comment: Registering a *listener* inside *BroadcastReceiver* does not make that listener a *wakeful*. Only receiving broadcasts ensures a wake lock for duration of `onReceive`. PhoneStateListener does not gurantees a wake lock.

Comment: @user1643723, So what should I do exactly? (Java or C# code would be appreciated)

Comment: Registering a BroadcastReceiver for `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` sounds like a good start. Naturally, registering receivers in Xamarin is described in [the documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.BroadcastReceiver/).